# How to redirect to j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

I have a `java spring mvc web application` and I have implemented the login part using `spring security`. The version of spring security that I use is `3.2.5`. My spring-security.xml file is as follows:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false" />


        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    </http>





<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
 class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
  <beans:property name="providers">
    <beans:list>
      <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Now I have a requirement where I will display some content initially and then the user has to login to view the full content. So I provide a sign in link which will bring up the sign in form. But when a user logs in, the default page is shown. I want the user to be redirected to the URL where the user is already in. I have also tried to POST the form to one of my custom controller methods and then redirect to spring security check from there. I intend to store the current URL to session from the method and redirect the user to that method from the default target method of spring security. But redirecting to spring security check is always giving me invalid username or password error since it is not able to authenticate the user. My custom method would be as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edu-login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String eduLogin(@ModelAttribute ("username") String username, @ModelAttribute ("password") String password, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes ra)
    {
        //My custom logic to stroe url to session
        ra.addAttribute("username", username);
        ra.addAttribute("password", password);
        return "redirect:/j_spring_security_check";
    }
```

Is there any solution for my problem. All I want is the user to return to the url on the browser after login.

Comment: Could you give an example (URLs) for the flow? What do you mean by *I want the user to be redirected to the URL where the user is already in*? Is that an static URL for all pages? Do you use the same URL for initially content and full content?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for your use case, but that's not the correct flow you should apply. More over, you cannot use `RedirectAttributes` this way, as it only applies in `MVC` layer and the `form-login`filter is in filter layer.

The sequence you are trying to achieve is this:

```
public_url > [login:if required] > private_url
```

For such a flow, there is a component you could take advantage of, which is [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html). As it states in the javadoc:

> An authentication success strategy which can make use of the [DefaultSavedRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.html) which may have been stored in the session by the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html). When such a request is intercepted and requires authentication, the request data is stored to record the original destination before the authentication process commenced, and to allow the request to be reconstructed when a redirect to the same URL occurs. This class is responsible for performing the redirect to the original URL if appropriate.

So, let's say your existing unprotected url is `/public/edu` and the second url (the protected one) is `/private/edu`.

In `/public/edu` you should provide a link to `/private/edu`. While accesing `/private/edu` the SpringSecurityFilterChain would check if the user is authenticated and  have the required authorizations.

- If the user is already authenticated the url will be reached directly.
- If not, it will redirected to login while it keeps the requested url `/private/edu` temporaly in session. Once the user performs a correct login, the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` will redirect the user to `/private/edu` instead of the default success url page.

This could be a sample config:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/private/edu" access="isAnonymous()" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestSuccesHandler" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="savedRequestSuccesHandler" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome" />     
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Note I've removed the `default-target-url="/welcome"` of the `<http>` element and introduced the property `authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestSuccesHandler"` which referers to a new bean I've just created:

```
<beans:bean id="savedRequestSuccesHandler" 
class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
      <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome" />   
</beans:bean>
```